# Extracting layer output from Classification model of SimpleTransformer

Tags: python, bert, text-classification

I have fine tuned a bert base model for text classification task. Now, I want to extract hidden layer output so as to combine this output with other features to train a random forest model. Problem lies in the fact that I don't know how to extract hidden layer output. It would be really great if someone can help me out in this regard.

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel

model_xlm = ClassificationModel('bert', 'bert-base-uncased')
model_xlm.train_model(df_train)
```